# Get the subdomain in a Django view? using django-hosts library

Tags: python, django, django-views, hosts, django-subdomains

I'm making a project in django. The aplication have to show diferent images and languages depending on the subdomain. For example: www.mysite.com will be the default page in english, but if the subdomain is mx.mysite.com the language must be spanish.

Whith django-hosts I can make that each subdomain redirect to a diferent django-app and I works well. The problem is that I want to make only one app to all diferent subdomains, only changing the language.

I think that is possible get the subdomain in a view and render the template with the language depending on the subdomain. But I don't know how to do it, please help.

THIS IS MY DJANGO HOSTS.PY where the host 'www' and 'mx' redirect to the same app 'mysite' but must be in diferent languages.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'www', 'mysite.urls', name='www'),
    host(r'help', 'help.urls', name='help'),
    host(r'mx', 'mysite.urls', name='mx'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## General solution

*Here's a general solution, which works with any supported language code and without the django-hosts package.*

Write a custom middleware, which checks the subdomain, and then sets the session variable LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY (or the cookie defined by LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME in settings.py. The default name is django_language.) with the language from the subdomain.

The custom middleware: (you can save it as middleware.py in the same folder as settings.py)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY


class SetLanguageFromSubdomain:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        host = request.get_host()

        # Parse language code from the host
        lang = host.split('.')[0]

        if lang == 'www':
           lang = 'en'

        # If requested language is in the languages supported by django,
        # language_session_key session variable is populated with the
        # supported language code.
        for django_language in settings.LANGUAGES:
            if django_language[0] == lang or django_language[0].endswith('-%s' % lang):
                request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = django_language[0]
                break

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Install this middleware between session and locale middlewares in settings.py

```
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #...
    # put the middleware here (change projectname to your project's name)
    'projectname.middleware.SetLanguageFromSubdomain',
    #...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```

More information about how django discovers language preference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

Languages supported by django: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py

More information about how to make a Django project translatable: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/

More information about writing a custom middleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Can you explain further how to get the subdomain only and load the appropriate templates?

Comment: You can get subdomain only, for example, by request.host.name.split('.')[0]. You can then set the language by setting the session variable LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY or cookie django_language. Please, check the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

Comment: Please add that to your answer, not to the comment section